# VS Code formatting

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code formats using 4 spaces instead of 2, in the settings the tab width is set to 2, and when I just press tab, it works fine and 2 spaces are put, but when I press ***Alt* *Shift F*** then 4 spaces are put.

[settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dbbS.png)

Comment: And alt+shift+F is the key binding for... ?

Comment: Please ask a question. I could imagine several questions from the facts you state. I do not want to answer all possible questions, just the one you ask :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution I had extension for js formatting and in the settings of this formatter, tab had 4 spaces

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need:

1. press right click
2. select "Format document with"
3. Be sure that you are formating your code with "Typescript and Javascript language feature" that is the default for VSCode.